# After minimal install Centos 6.5 doesn't see network

Tags: linux, installation, centos

I installed an minimal Centos 6.5 (with standart VGA) on my laptop beside Windows 7 as dual boot.

Now I want to install some extra features like XWindows but Centos doesn't reach the internet.
It says "PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"

Note: This is my first time trying Linux.

Comment: For a first-timer, I would suggest something possibly more user-friendly, such as Fedora or Ubuntu. // Also, I suggest that you don't use a minimal install; that's more of an expert option, and will be very minimal.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to learn this. Is driver loading made with kernels? How can I tell Centos to look in CD drive or USB drive for updates?

Comment: Well, I gave up. I made a full install.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually edit

> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

If you're using a DHCP server to get an IP, you should have a line that says

> BOOTPROTO=dhcp

Then, do a

> service network restart

Other way:

> ifconfig eth0 up
>
> dhclient eth0

would grab an interface IP and DNS resolver via DHCP and automatically insert a default route.

Comment: ifcgf-eth0 seems fine to me, but for `service network restart` there is message "Device eth0 dos not seem to be present"...

Comment: Sometimes the names of the network interfaces are different. Try using `dmesg | less` or `ifconfig -a` to find their names.

Answer (score 0):

In file

> /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0

turn `ONBOOT=yes`